# Looping through multiple server using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have the exact same table on multiple different servers that I would like to select from with the same query. Right now I have the IPs of those server stored in a table and then looping through the IP table and appending the IP into a query string then execute a dynamic query. Any better way to do this or avoid the dynamic query?

My query is kind of long and I don't want to write it in one line for the query string.

Comment: Executing the query from where? SSMS? A client application you have written? An ETL tool?

Comment: this is in sql management studio as stored procedure

Comment: SSMS has native support for this. Create registered servers, stick em in a registered server group, then right click the group folder in SSMS and open a new query window. SSMS will connect to all servers in the group. You then type your query once, execute it, and it will execute on all servers in the group. Old but probably still accurate article [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2855/sql-server-multi-database-query-with-registered-servers/)

Comment: yes that is what Im trying to do I guess the hassle part would be setting up the group